# Is there a better way to calculate a time period?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, performance, nsdate

I have the following code. This is getting calculated in cellForRowAtIndexPath, so I think it could be a little expensive. Is there a better way to calculate a time period?

```
+(NSString*)toShortTimeIntervalString:(NSString*)sDate  
{ 
    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
    NSDate* date = [df dateFromString:[sDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Z" withString:@"-0000"]];
    [df release];

    NSDate* today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSDate *d = date; //[_twitter_dateFormatter dateFromString:sDate];
    NSTimeInterval interval = [today timeIntervalSinceDate:d];
    [today release];

    //TODO: added ABS wrapper
    double res = 0;
    NSString* result;
    if(interval > SECONDS_IN_WEEK)
    {
        res = fabs(interval / SECONDS_IN_WEEK);
        result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0fw ago", res];
    }
    else if(interval > SECONDS_IN_DAY)
    {
        res = fabs(interval / SECONDS_IN_DAY);
        result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0fd ago", res];
    }
    else if (interval > SECONDS_IN_HOUR){
        res = fabs(interval / SECONDS_IN_HOUR);
        result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0fh ago", res];
    }
    else if (interval > SECONDS_IN_MIN) {
        res = fabs(interval / SECONDS_IN_MIN);
        result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0fm ago", res];
    }
    else
    {
        interval = fabs(interval);
        result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0fs ago", interval];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: That looks fine to me and I doubt that it is too slow.

Comment: Don't assume, measure. If you measure it and it's too slow, figure out what's making it that way, and then ask how to improve that. If you don't know how to measure or how to profile, then ask about that. "Do you think this is too slow?" isn't really a good SO question.

Comment: Josh, I measured it and it takes up 62% of time spent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look too bad, and I doubt you'll be seeing too much of a performance hit from it. To make it more efficient, you might consider only creating one NSDataFormatter (saving it in an instance variable or `static` variable) and reusing it. Or even better, if you could convert everything to NSDates beforehand, then you wouldn't have to use the formatter every time.

Are you actually seeing any performance issues here, though? Before you try and optimize, you should use Instruments to investigate what's actually taking up time.

Comment: The Time Profiler shows 62% of time is spent on that method during during cell creation. Should I be using a different instrument to measure?

Comment: Time profiler is the right tool here. And caching the date formatted is definitely the right place to start; initializing a new formatted is actually fairly expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, but there are a [few categories](https://github.com/billymeltdown/nsdate-helper) out there which encapsulate that logic and make it a one line call for you.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I've been in a situation to perform complex calculation (plotting graph for series of years), and I was using NSDate within loops. After analyze with time profiler NSDate, NSDateFormater, NSCalendar was the root cause. I switched to use the C type ([time_t + timeinfo](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/localtime/)) and it drastically improves the speed.

Although they are much faster, they have less functionality, if you need to deal with TimeZone etc, NSDate is probably easier to deal with.